# Data serialization protocol for Dynamic message and TLV?

Tags: c++, networking, protocol-buffers, thrift-protocol

Is there any data serialization protocol which allows `dynamic message types` and `TLV kind of encoding` of data ?, after looking at Protocol Buffer and Apache thrift they don't seem to do so.

I have some requirement, for eg: if i want to send some data structures :

1. It must have some way to encode data (like in Type length value encoding), so that receiver knows that what its reading and how data is arranged(something like a data tree).Protocl buffers says you have to keep track of your data  on receiver side.
2. It should also provide some way so that i can add data dynamically.I think in PB and thrift they need to know all data in advance, am i correct ?

Do only alternative is encode Data structure in TLV format by your own and then use something like boost::serialization to serilize it over the wire ?

Answer (score 1):

Protobufs can be self-describing if you bundle your message with a `DescirptorSet`.  See [Self-describing Messages](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#self-description) from the docs.  You can even generate new descriptors (new proto types) at runtime if you really want.

That said, it sounds like you'd be happier with JSON or MsgPack, which are schema-less encodings.

Comment: As it looks in XML only key value combination is possible but i need to consider length of data type as well because i am using a socket to transport this data and receiver may not be able to differentiate between variable length  the data types(string). However for data hierarchy it looks fine.

Comment: It seems that Protocol Buffers were not meant to build dynamic and self-describing messages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something more generic like JSON or Binary JSON? It doesn't specify length perse but the length is discoverable quite easily. There is plenty of C++ library support for it as well.